# navigator.share is not working in a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, navigator

Is there a reason why the `navigator.share()` JavaScript function is not working inside a WebView of my Android app? When accessing the same URL through the web browser, the native Android share dialog pops up, but not when accessing the URL from the WebView of my app.

- The URL is using https.
- The share action is user-triggered by an onClick.
- `setJavaScriptEnabled` is set to `true`.
- `setDomStorageEnabled` is also set to `true`.

Comment: My guess is it is the same reason that window.print does not work in web views - whatever that may be

Comment: any solution yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eventually, I used the following settings for my webviews. There is a bit more to it for me than just the `navigator.share`, but what works for me might work for others. Worth a try.

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptShareInterface(), "AndroidShareHandler");
```

The AndroidShareHandler will become a global JavaScript function which will be available in the webview and can be triggered by a button click for example:

Java:

```
package com.your.package;

import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

public class JavaScriptShareInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void share(String url) {
        // your share action
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
shareButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.AndroidShareHandler.share('https://stackoverflow.com');
});
```

Comment: I've used above settings. But from where JavaScriptShareInterface came? I can't find such class. 

Can you help or post full code?

Comment: @MilindMevada I have updated my answer. The interface function(s) will become available in JavaScript.

Comment: Can you please add each path file, which java and javascript  files have to be edited and what is mWebView?

Comment: This is android share,  not webshare,

Comment: @AkinZeman that's why this question is tagged with Android and I mention it's regarding an Android app in my initial question.